# UIProgressView Subclassing for custom Colors

Tags: ios, uiview, colors, uiprogressview

I'm trying to subclass ProgressView to use as a health bar for a game and when I try to override the setProgress, it isn't called.

I want the color to change based on the progress float value.

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
@interface AHHealthbar : UIProgressView
...
- (void)setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated
{

if (progress > .5)
{
    self.progressTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

if (progress <= .5 && self.progress >= .2)
{
    self.progressTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

if (progress < .2) {
    self.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

}

[super setProgress:progress animated:animated];
}
```

Does any one have an idea of how to override this? Or any better ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you properly initiate it as AHHealthbar (not UIProgressView) it's easy to forget this, especially when initiated from a NIB file. Check your variable pointer type in the debugger.

Comment: I can confirm that AHHealthbar is being instantiated, but my setProgress method is never called. I made an override of drawrect that was called. But I don't want to do the drawing myself, just the colors.

Comment: Well, did you try overriding `-setProgress:`?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to override....

Answer (score 1):

You might need to also override `-setProgress:`.